# Remove .php suffix from URLs

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying hard to remove .php from main directory and all my subdirectories but it doesnt work. I used the following code. 
If i still enter the files within the directory in the address with /test.php how can I have it redirect to just /test. 
Nothing of the below works. Also is the htaccess file on the public_html folder or on the root?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on RewriteEngine On RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension snippet

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

However in my sub-directory I have htaccess for mysql links like below and it works.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test\/([0-9]+)$ test.php?id=$1
```

Comment: Use `%{REQUEST_URI}` instead of `%{THE_REQUEST}`

Comment: `public_html` should be root isn't it? Also why do you have 2 different .htaccess? Do you really need .htaccess in sub directory?

Answer (score 0):

For your question on where to place the `.htaccess` file, you find that outlined here:

- [Apache HTTP Server Tutorial: .htaccess files](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html) - An interesting part here is the [How directives are applied](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html#how) section.

With focus on the *Mod Rewrite*, there is a relation between the location of the `.htaccess` file and the conditions and rules you use for URL-rewriting with *Mod Rewrite*. This is controlled by the

- [RewriteBase Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase)

However in your example it's far more trivial: Use `%{REQUEST_URI}` instead of `%{THE_REQUEST}`. It's easier to parse (check against) *and*  the query string is separated from it.